# How to return multiple regex values as a tuple

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am working on a Python program that searches through received emails and returns coordinates. I am trying to create a regular expression to select the Lat/long values from a string. (I am new to regex)

Here is a small example of one of the strings I have been using for testing:

```
     content = """

WorkLocationBoundingBox
Latitude:30.556555Longitude:-97.659824
SecondLatitude:30.569138SecondLongitude:-97.650855

     """
```

I came up with `Latitude:(\d+).(\d+)Longitude:(.*)`, which I believe is close to what I need, but it sperates `30` and `556555` into seperate groups. But, `-97.659824` is correctly placed into a group.

My ideal expected result would look something this:

```
[(30.556555, -97.659824, 30.569138, -97.650855)]
```

Comment: Try it like this `Latitude:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)Longitude:(.*)` or more precise `(?:Second)?Latitude:(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:Second)?Longitude:(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` See https://regex101.com/r/OZgPXb/1

Comment: Worked great, now to spend the time to figure out why! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3 capture groups, where the first group is used to match up the word before Long or Latitude.

```
((?:Second)?)Latitude:(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\1Longitude:(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

- `((?:Second)?)` Capture group 1, optionally match `Second`
- `Latitude:` Match literally
- `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture **group 2**, match an optional `-` then 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `\1Longitude:` A Backreference to what is matched in group 1 and match `Longitude:`
- `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture **group 3**, match an optional `-` then 1+ digits with an optional decimal part

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yRMDtB/1) or a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/oIWLOX)

```
import re
regex = r"((?:Second)?)Latitude:(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\1Longitude:(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
s = ("WorkLocationBoundingBox\n"
            "Latitude:30.556555Longitude:-97.659824\n"
            "SecondLatitude:30.569138SecondLongitude:-97.650855")

matches = re.finditer(regex, s)
lst = []

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
     lst.append(match.group(2))
     lst.append(match.group(3))

print(lst)
```

Output

```
['30.556555', '-97.659824', '30.569138', '-97.650855']
```

---

A bit less strict pattern could be matching optional word character before either Longitude or Latitude:

```
\w*Latitude:(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\w*Longitude:(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1di8ye/1)

In that case, you might also use re.findall to return the group values in a list of tuples if you want:

```
import re

pattern = r"\w*Latitude:(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\w*Longitude:(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"

s = ("WorkLocationBoundingBox\n"
            "Latitude:30.556555Longitude:-97.659824\n"
            "SecondLatitude:30.569138SecondLongitude:-97.650855")
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
[('30.556555', '-97.659824'), ('30.569138', '-97.650855')]
```

Comment: A very thorough and helpful answer. Thanks again for your help!